# Faster awk script to get the substring / string we wanted

Tags: shell-script, awk, performance

```
ORDER EVENT .........[] [] ... so many other tags... [Account<25106>=ACCT1] [Destination...] .. so many other tags.
```

I am currently trying to get the account like this. I tried using match in awk, but it seems slower. Can you suggest anything else other than the one below which is even faster?

```
j = index($0, "<25106>=");
account=substr($0, j + accountTagLength);
account=substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);
```

Account is not 2nd field and the field position my vary..

Timings:

```
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 temp.log | awk -F'<25106>=' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/].*//' > /dev/null

real    0m2.410s
user    0m2.782s
sys     0m0.319s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 temp.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m1.690s
user    0m1.737s
sys     0m0.448s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 temp.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m1.588s
user    0m1.733s
sys     0m0.179s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 temp.log | awk -F'<25106>=' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/].*//' > /dev/null                               
real    0m2.384s
user    0m2.762s
sys     0m0.272s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 temp.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m1.703s
user    0m1.709s
sys     0m0.484s

bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | gawk 'match($0, /<25106>=([^]]+)/, ary) {account = ary[1]}'

real    0m3.449s
user    0m3.661s
sys     0m0.290s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | gawk 'match($0, /<25106>=([^]]+)/, ary) {account = ary[1]}'

real    0m3.410s
user    0m3.551s
sys     0m0.236s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | gawk 'match($0, /<25106>=([^]]+)/, ary) {account = ary[1]}'

real    0m3.361s
user    0m3.487s
sys     0m0.286s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m1.626s
user    0m1.831s
sys     0m0.263s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | awk -F '<25106>=' '{split($2, ary, /\]/); account = ary[1]}'

real    0m2.721s
user    0m2.808s
sys     0m0.265s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | awk -F '<25106>=' '{split($2, ary, /\]/); account = ary[1]}'

real    0m2.787s
user    0m2.863s
sys     0m0.516s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | awk -F '<25106>=' '{split($2, ary, /\]/); account = ary[1]}'

real    0m2.724s
user    0m2.882s
sys     0m0.278s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 dumper/cam_verbose.20120220.000.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m1.576s
user    0m1.748s
sys     0m0.235s

bash-3.2$ time head -100000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120224.log | grep -oE '<25106>=([A-Za-z0-9]*)+' | cut -d= -f2 > /dev/null                                     
real    0m2.098s
user    0m2.131s
sys     0m0.033s
bash-3.2$ time head -100000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120224.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); print substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }' > /dev/null

real    0m0.253s
user    0m0.275s
sys     0m0.040s
bash-3.2$ time head -100000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120224.log | grep -oE '<25106>=([A-Za-z0-9]*)+' | cut -d= -f2 > /dev/null                                     
real    0m2.070s
user    0m2.105s
sys     0m0.034s
bash-3.2$ time head -100000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120224.log | grep -oE '<25106>=([A-Za-z0-9]*)+' > /dev/null

real    0m2.065s
user    0m2.090s
sys     0m0.037s
    bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120228.log | awk -F'<25106>=' '{ substr($2,0,index($2,"]")-1);}'

real    0m3.426s
user    0m3.637s
sys     0m0.412s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120228.log | awk -F'<25106>=' '{ substr($2,0,index($2,"]")-1);}'

real    0m3.463s
user    0m3.603s
sys     0m0.408s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120228.log | awk '{j = index($0, "25106>="); if (j > 0) { account=substr($0, j + 7); substr(account,1,index(account, "]") - 1);} }'

real    0m2.247s
user    0m2.307s
sys     0m0.649s
```

Comment: just found out even though I am not looking for a grep solution, regular expressions with grep are so slow.

Comment: Of course the literal string comparison is going to be faster than any regex comparison. And what you propose above is the straightforward implementation of that; so I wouldn't expect there to be anythin faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F'<25106>=' '{print substr($2,0,index($2,"]")-1);}'
```

Not using regex, just strict string operations.

Comment: even that is slower than the `index` and `substring`. I updated the stats, if you go to the `end`.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only print this number, you can try this:

```
echo "ORDER EVENT ......... [Account<25106>=ACCT1]" | awk -F'<25106>=' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/].*//'
```

EDIT: sed -only solution:

```
echo "ORDER EVENT ......... [Account<25106>=ACCT1]" | sed -e 's/.*25106>=//' -e 's/].*//'
```

EDIT2:

```
awk '{if (split($0, a, "25106>=") > 1) {print substr(a[2], 0, index(a[2], "]")-1)} }'
```

Comment: sorry, Jan, I was vague in my explanation of question. It is not 2nd field and the field position my vary. I updated my question.

Comment: @srikanthradix Updated.

Comment: updated with timings using time command. still `index + substring` seems to be faster.

Comment: @srikanthradix will be solution with only sed more faster?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find out whether there is anything faster only with `awk`.

Comment: just out of curiosity, I tried with `sed-only` solution. It is way slow.

`bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120228.log | sed -e 's/.*25106>=//' -e 's/].*//' > /dev/null

real    0m9.956s
user    0m10.167s
sys     0m0.441s
bash-3.2$ time head -1000000 ORDER_EVENTS_CHAS_20120228.log | sed -e 's/.*25106>=//' -e 's/].*//' > /dev/null

real    0m10.083s
user    0m10.254s
sys     0m0.343s`

Comment: @srikanthradix I've tried to add another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk (`gawk`) you can use the `match()` function with capturing parentheses:

```
gawk 'match($0, /<25106>=([^]]+)/, ary) {account = ary[1]}'
```

Alternately, you can use a complex field separator:

```
awk -F '<25106>=' '{split($2, ary, /\]/); account = ary[1]}'
```

Comment: anything with `regex` like match is `slow`. I have tried. I have updated the timings.